# InnoDB Failure of some kind

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have MySQL 5.5 installed. I tried to install Joolma but it failed. I went into their sql and replace EGNINE=InnoDB with MyISAM and the install worked.

InnoDB is listed under SHOW ENGINES;

Any idea what the cause is or how to fix this so other InnoDB sites can be used?

I had these errors:

```
MySQL ERROR No: 1030
MysqL Error: Got error -1 from storage engine
```

Comment: Did you ever get this solved ???

Answer (score 1):

check your my.cnf file to see if there is anything force innodb to recover

```
force_innodb_recovery
```

take a look to this topic that talk about similar problem [Got error -1 from storage engine](http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/error-1030-hy000-got-error--1-from-storage-engine-291134.html)

or make sure the /tmp partition or the partition the MySQL databases are stored on is not full.

Comment: Yes, I do have that. It is set to 6

Comment: try to make it 4, do u have checked the /tmp partition or the partition the MySQL databases are stored on is not full? , reffer for [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html) to know more about force_innodb_recovery

Comment: Try to make it 4 does not make sense.  You need 0 (default) at all times unless you are in the middle of trying to recover from data corruption.  You cannot do inserts with innodb_force_recovery set to any nonzero value.  It is an emergency only setting. If it was already 6 you likely have an unstable installation and should not be deploying new databases on it.

Comment: If you are using force_innodb_recovery the chances are you have had issues with innodb tables in the past and had to add this into my.cnf to allow mysql to start without checking the innodb tables. At level 6 you would be able to read from the tables but wouldn't be able to create, edit update etc. Try setting the value to 0 (or remove it completely) and restart mysql. If it restarts then great if not then you will need to have a look at the innodb tables you have and correct the 1 causing the issue.